# plot that only shows most recent points

Tags: python

I want to make a real time plot of temeperature vs. iteration but I will end up having so many points that it would not make sense to have them on the same plot. Does anyone know of any good ways to only show the most recent (lets say 100) data points so that after the first 100 the plot starts to replace the old data points with the new data points?

I thought it would be easier without code but here is the real time ploting that I have now.

```
from time import sleep
from labjack import ljm
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open T7 over USB
handle = ljm.openS("T7", "USB", "ANY")

# Configure thermocouple line on AIN0
ljm.eWriteName(handle, "AIN0_EF_INDEX", 22)  # Feature index for type K thermocouple
ljm.eWriteName(handle, "AIN0_EF_CONFIG_A", 1)  # Units. Default = Kelvin. 1 = Celsius. 2 = Fahrenheit.
ljm.eWriteName(handle, "AIN0_EF_CONFIG_B", 60052)  # CJC source, address for device temperature sensor
ljm.eWriteName(handle, "AIN0_EF_CONFIG_D", 1.0)  # Slope for CJC reading
ljm.eWriteName(handle, "AIN0_EF_CONFIG_E", 0.0)  # Offset for CJC reading

temperature = []
x = list()
y = list()
x1 = list()
y1 = list()
dT_tol = .5

plt.ion()
fig=plt.figure()

# Read loop
for i in range(60):
    # Get the thermocouple reading on AIN0. 
    tempC = ljm.eReadName(handle, "AIN0_EF_READ_A")
    temperature.append(tempC)
    dT = temperature[i]-temperature[i-1]

    if -dT_tol<dT<dT_tol:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT, "         " "Steady State" 
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT
        sleep(1) 



    #Plotting
    plt.figure(1)   
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.axis([0,60,0,80])
    x.append(i)
    y.append(temperature[i])
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (C)')

    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.axis([0,60,-4,4])
    x1.append(i)
    y1.append(dT)
    plt.scatter(x1,y1,zorder = 2)

    #Set dT steady state boundaries
    plt.axhspan(-dT_tol, dT_tol, color='#87CEFA', alpha=1, zorder = 1)

    plt.ylabel('dT')
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(.0001)

# Close handle
ljm.close(handle)
```

Comment: Without code, or even a mention of what graphing library you're using (matplotlib?) it'll be hard to answer this.

Comment: I just added the code. I thought it may complicate things but I guess I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

you can use list of array to show the all  data given for a while.
for example

tempaturelist=[]

```
for i in range(50):

      enter code here

tempaturelist.append(tempature)
print tempaturelist
```

There is a overwriting if you use same variable for all values.
Thats why you see only most recent values .

Comment: yes this does print out my most recent T but I need a plot that can outright replace the old data and update it with new data. This method does update the data but it still plots the entire list on the plot. No replacement of points at all

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

You might consider using a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque) object to improve performance. It is like a stack/queue hybrid, which may be faster than numpy.roll. I left the old code in for example..

```
from collections import deque
```

You can use something like this, just update it to fit your needs ( I am just going to make up random data because im too lazy to use your example)

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

buffer_size = 100 # how many data points you want to plot at any given time
#data_buffer = np.zeros( buffer_size) # this is where you will keep the latest data points
data_buffer = deque()
for i in range( buffer_size):
    data_buffer.append(0)

temperatures = np.random.random( 200 ) # some random temperature data, i dunno

# setup the figure
fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.suptitle('Previous %d temperatures'%buffer_size, fontsize=12)
ax = plt.gca()

for i,Temp in enumerate( temperatures ):
    #data_buffer = np.roll( data_buffer, shift=-1)
    #data_buffer[ -1] = Temp
    data_buffer.popleft()
    data_buffer.append( Temp)
    ax.plot( data_buffer, 'rs', ms=6) # whatever style you want...
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
    plt.cla() # clears the axis
```

I won't post the output of this plot because it will always be changing, but try it yourself ;)